# Is my form safe from spam bots?

Tags: jquery, forms, security

I thought of a simple way of securing my form from spam bots. I want to check with you guys if you think it will be sufficient. It's only a contact form, so I don't need extreme security, just so the e-mail address doesn't get spammed.

Let's say I build the form like this:

```
<div id="unlock">Click 3 times to unlock the form</div>

<form action="url">
<input type="email" />
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

And then with a simple javascript/jQuery I check if the #unlock has been clicked 3 times. If that's the case, I just add the name attribute to the form elements, like so:

```
$('input[type=email]').attr('name', 'senderEmail');
```

The assumption I'm making is that the bot will not be able to submit the form correctly because it doesn't know the names of the form elements. Of course I'll check if the form values are correct on the server, and if not, the form will not be submitted. Is this assumption correct? I guess that it would be possible to do the same but instead add the action attribute to the form tag?!
That way the bots shouldn't know the recieving URL?!

Like I said, I'm not securing anything super important, but I just want to stop the "generic" spam bots.

Comment: Why not just use reCaptcha? Then you don't have to worry about outsmarting the bots.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something exactly like that before. I was amazed that it didn't keep my inbox from getting spammed (I was only safe for about two months).

I think that if your site draws enough attention, some kid somewhere is going to get paid a couple dollars to write a quick script to defeat whatever security you devised like that.

I would suggest using OpenId to authenticate people before the user can use that form. I know it's not 100% safe as well, but it's safer than such bot-detecting methods and less annoying than a captcha. And these days everyone has accounts in at least a few of the major OpenId identity providers.

Answer (score 1):

There 's different solution to prevent spam bots:

- captcha
- honey pot (add a field that is not displayed (display:none but not type=hidden) and if this field is filled, you know on the server side that it is a bot
- check time between request and response (a human will read the page, fill the form, etc.)
- build and submit the form via javascript (as you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reasons why this should not work? Of course a human could easily read your script and figure out what's going on and afterwards feed a bot with the correct input names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're on a good path, maybe you should add some randomization that might help with defending against what Regan is talking about.

Good luck!